# Imagemagcik Smask

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, imagemagick

I extracted the raw data from PDF and tried to convert it to BMP using Imagemagick.

The language is Python3.
But DeviceRGB with **Smask** was not converted correctly and it didn't look like original image.

- Original Image

```
...
ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/
BitsPerComponent 8/
Interpolate false/
SMask 31 0 R/
Filter/FlateDecode/
Length 24011>>
stream...
```

- XObject

```
...
31 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/
Subtype/Image/
Width 414/
Height 165/
ColorSpace/DeviceGray/
Matte[ 0 0 0] /
BitsPerComponent 8/
Interpolate false/
Filter/FlateDecode/
Length 11979>>
stream
...
```

Here is the imagemagick command to convert the raw data.

```
sub_proc_cmd = [
    'convert',
    '-size', str(json_data['Width']) + 'x' + str(json_data['Height']),
    '-depth', str(json_data['BitsPerComponent']),
    '-colorspace', 'RGB',
    raw_image,
    'BMP3:' + raw_image + '.bmp']
proc_status = subprocess.check_call(sub_proc_cmd)
```

Original Image:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bbub.png)

Converted Image:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HApUX.png)

Comment: Your original is a PNG not PDF. Post a zipped version of the PDF. What is an Smask? If you have a PDF with an imbedded image, you should use pdfimages to extract the raster file. See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwje_YL_tpbsAhXDpJ4KHWWECPsQFjABegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmanpages.debian.org%2Ftesting%2Fpoppler-utils%2Fpdfimages.1.en.html&usg=AOvVaw3nEYiX2TIBTjB5CHSPpqLk

Comment: For some reasons, I can't use pdfimages. @fmw42